# OCaml unbound variable

Tags: module, ocaml, type-inference

I am implementing an NFA with Ocaml and the compiler gives me an error at this line

```
module Nfa : NFA =
struct

type transition = int * char option * int
type nfa = int * int list * transition list

let make_nfa s fs ts = nfa (s, fs, ts);;
```

The error is at the last line where the compiler says `Error: Unbound value nfa`

I am not sure what the problem is... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transition` and `nfa` are tuple type synonyms, not type constructors. Assuming you want `make_nfa` to be of type `int -> int list -> transition list -> nfa`, it would be simply

```
let make_nfa s fs ts = (s, fs, ts)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have nowhere declared the `value` nfa.  You have only declared the `type` nfa.

As in

```
type nfa_type = int * int list * transitian list
let nfa = ( 1, [ 1; 2; 3 ], [x;y] )
```

edit: apologies for the typos I was in javascript mode

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `nfa` as a constructor.  But your type `nfa` doesn't define a constructor.  It's just a synonym for a tuple type.  So a value of the type would look like `(3, [4], [])`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `nfa` is a synonym (like a typedef) for the tuple type `int * int list * transition list`.

You seem to want to use it like the constructor of an algebraic data type. If you want to do that, you would do something like this:

```
type nfa = Nfa of int * int list * transition list

let make_nfa s fs ts = Nfa (s, fs, ts)
```

But an algebraic data type with 1 constructor in this case is kind of a waste.